# How do get the key name in a dict, without having to name each key name?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have dict defined with a lot of sub elements:

```
kernel:
  vm:
    swappiness: 0
    dirty_background_ratio: 123
    dirty_ratio: 123
    dirty_expire_centisecs: 123
  sys:
    fs:
      file_max: 123456
  net:
    ipv4:
      tcp_max_syn_backlog: 123456
      tcp_slow_start_after_idle: 0
      tcp_abort_on_overflow: 1
    core:
      somaxconn: 123456
      netdev_max_backlog: 123456
      rmem_max: 123456
      wmem_max: 123456
      rmem_default: 123456
      rmem_max: 123456
```

And I have a task (not working) below as an example of what I'm trying to do to set the kernel parameters.

```
- name: "Tune kernel parameters"
  sysctl:
    name: "{{ item.key }}"
    value: "{{ item.value[item.key] }}"
    state: present
    sysctl_set: yes
  with_subelements:
    - kernel
```

How can each item the dict be set without having to name each key name?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"without having to name each key name"*?

Comment: @NPE Thanks for the quick reply. The docs ( http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements ) shows that the key's name needs to be named. For example: "name" in `{{ item.0.name }}`, which is "alice". I would have to name each keys. For example, I think that I would have to do `{{ item.0.net.core.somaxconn }}`. Since more sub-dicts maybe added/removed, I rather get the key, say `{{ item.key }}`, and the key's value, say `{{ item.value[item.key} }}`. I don't know what the correct syntax do that or if it's even possible. I just need the name of the key and its value

Comment: here's another example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908715/ansible-with-subelements where the keys' names have to be listed (surname, name and age). I don't want to have to update the task with a new sub element's key name every time there's a new dict+value added.

Comment: I bet this is possible only with custom filter plugin for Ansible, as I see no other way to flatten nested dictionary into a list of dot-separated strings.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over dictionaries

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3} 

for key, value in d.iteritems():

      print key,value
```

Comment: I need to do this in Ansible without adding python code. I removed the python tags. How do I do this in Ansible? (version 2.3.1 at the moment).