# Ansible with_subelements nested levels

Tags: arrays, list, loops, nested, ansible

I'm trying to iterate through nested loops, much like this question:

[Ansible with_subelements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908715/ansible-with-subelements)

I need to go an extra level deep though. The comment there (dated January 2017) states that additional levels of nesting are unsupported. Is this still the case? If not, how can I reference deeper levels?

My data:

```
dns:
  - name: Something
    prefix: st
    zones:
      - zone: something.com
        records:
          - record: testing.something.com
            type: TXT
            value: '"somethingtest"'
            ttl: 60

  - name: Devthing
    prefix: dt
    zones:
      - zone: devthing.com
        records:
          - record: testing.devthing.com
            type: TXT
            value: '"devthingtest"'
            ttl: 60
      - zone: testthing.com
        records:
          - record: testing.testthing.com
            type: TXT
            value: '"testthingtest"'
            ttl: 60
          - record: thingy.testthing.com
            type: TXT
            value: '"testthingthingytest"'
            ttl: 60
```

My task:

```
- name: Create DNS records
  route53:
    state: present
    zone: "{{ item.0.zone }}"
    record: "{{ item.1.record }}"
    type: "{{ item.1.type }}"
    ttl: "{{ item.1.ttl }}"
    value:  "{{ item.1.value }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ dns }}"
    - records
```

Zones, users and access policies are successfully created since they don't need to go that extra level deep (records level).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need `name` and `prefix` from root dict, you can reduce original list to plain list of zones:

```
with_subelements:
  - "{{ dns | map(attribute='zones') | list | sum(start=[]) }}"
  - records
```

And – no - nested subelements is still not supported.

*Update* in case parent options are required, some preprocessing is required:

```
- set_fact:
    zones_loop: >
      {{ zones_loop|d([])
        + [ {} | combine(item[0]) | combine(item[1]) ]
      }}
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ dns }}"
    - zones

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ zones_loop }}"
    - records
```

With first task we loop over each `zone` and attach/combine parent's keys to them, forming new `zones_loop` list. Second task is the same, but we loop over our generated list.

Comment: This works perfectly - name and prefix were only needed for other tasks. Many thanks!