# Ansible combine "complex" dictionary

Tags: loops, filter, ansible

Let's say I have the following variables :

```
services:
  - name: export
    command: "php app/console export"
  - name: import
    command: "php app/console import"

contextes:
  - site_name: mysite
    stages:
      - stage_name: prod
        url: http://mysite.fr
        db:
          name: mysitedb_prod
          user: myuserdb_prod
        # more and more attributes, some simple, some list, some dictionaries
      - stage_name: qualif
        url: http://qualif.mysite.fr
        db:
          name: mysitedb_qualif
          user: mysiteuser_qualif
  - site_name: my2dsite
    stages:
      - stage_name: prod
        url: http://mysite2.fr
        db:
          name: mysite2db_prod
          user: myuser2db_prod
```

I want to transform them to have the following variable structure :

```
my_var:
  - site_name: mysite
    stage_name: prod
    services:
      - name: export
        command: "php app/console export"
      - name: import
        command: "php app/console import"
  - site_name: mysite
    stage_name: qualif
    services:
      - name: export
        command: "php app/console export"
      - name: import
        command: "php app/console import"
  - site_name: my2dsite
    stage_name: prod
    services:
      - name: export
        command: "php app/console export"
      - name: import
        command: "php app/console import"
```

(the final purpose is to create same systemD services for all my sites/stages)

I tried multiple thing based on set_fact and with_subelement loop.

I tought [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49772324) could help me but the problem is not the same and I don't understand the trnasformation made to adapt them.
(Note if I repeat services in all site_name/stage_name it work but I would to avoid it)

Note : I can't change the "contextes" variable structure, my all ansible infrastructure is based on.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I would just write  a filter plugin (or custom module) and perform this transformation in Python rather than trying to shoehorn it into Ansible syntax. Ansible is in general really bad at data manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I generally agree with @larsk comment on ansible capacity to deal with complex data manipulation, the current problem is not as hard as it seems and can have a fairly concise "ansible only" solution.

My solution relies on the use of a [subelements loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements)

```
---
- name: Loop on subelements
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    services:
      - name: export
        command: "php app/console export"
      - name: import
        command: "php app/console import"

    contextes:
      - site_name: mysite
        stages:
          - stage_name: prod
            url: http://mysite.fr
            db:
              name: mysitedb_prod
              user: myuserdb_prod
            # more and more attributes, some simple, some list, some dictionaries
          - stage_name: qualif
            url: http://qualif.mysite.fr
            db:
              name: mysitedb_qualif
              user: mysiteuser_qualif
      - site_name: my2dsite
        stages:
          - stage_name: prod
            url: http://mysite2.fr
            db:
              name: mysite2db_prod
              user: myuser2db_prod

  tasks:
    - name: Construct my new data structure
      vars:
        current_hash:
          site_name: "{{ item.0.site_name }}"
          stage_name: "{{ item.1.stage_name }}"
          services: "{{ services }}"
      set_fact:
        my_var: "{{ my_var | default([]) + [current_hash] }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', contextes, 'stages') }}"

    - name: Show calculated var
      debug:
        var: my_var
```

Which gives

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [Loop on subelements] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Construct my new data structure] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'site_name': 'mysite'}, {'stage_name': 'prod', 'url': 'http://mysite.fr', 'db': {'name': 'mysitedb_prod', 'user': 'myuserdb_prod'}}])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'site_name': 'mysite'}, {'stage_name': 'qualif', 'url': 'http://qualif.mysite.fr', 'db': {'name': 'mysitedb_qualif', 'user': 'mysiteuser_qualif'}}])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'site_name': 'my2dsite'}, {'stage_name': 'prod', 'url': 'http://mysite2.fr', 'db': {'name': 'mysite2db_prod', 'user': 'myuser2db_prod'}}])

TASK [Show calculated var] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var": [
        {
            "services": [
                {
                    "command": "php app/console export",
                    "name": "export"
                },
                {
                    "command": "php app/console import",
                    "name": "import"
                }
            ],
            "site_name": "mysite",
            "stage_name": "prod"
        },
        {
            "services": [
                {
                    "command": "php app/console export",
                    "name": "export"
                },
                {
                    "command": "php app/console import",
                    "name": "import"
                }
            ],
            "site_name": "mysite",
            "stage_name": "qualif"
        },
        {
            "services": [
                {
                    "command": "php app/console export",
                    "name": "export"
                },
                {
                    "command": "php app/console import",
                    "name": "import"
                }
            ],
            "site_name": "my2dsite",
            "stage_name": "prod"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Not so hard, not so hard...
It depend for who :D

Thanks a lot