# Loop through subelements of subelements

Tags: loops, ansible, nested, nested-lists, ansible-2.x

I am using the following data structure in Ansible:

```yaml
datacenters:
  - name: Datacenter1
    clusters:
      - name: ClusterA
        hosts:
          - 192.168.0.1
          - 192.168.0.2
      - name: ClusterB
        hosts:
          - 192.168.1.1
          - 192.168.1.2
  - name: Datacenter2
    clusters:
      - name: ClusterC
        hosts:
          - 192.168.2.1
          - 192.168.2.2
```

In a task, I want to iterate over each *host* while having access to the data of all the parent layers. If there is only one nesting level, it can easily be done with the `subelements` filter:

```
loop: '{{ datacenters | subelements(''clusters'') }}'
```

This will give me access to the data like this:

```
'Datacenter: {{ item.0.name }}, Cluster: {{ item.1.name }}'
```

I was hoping to be able to extend this concept like this:

```
loop: '{{ datacenters | subelements(''clusters'') | subelements(''hosts'') }}'
```

And being able to access the data like this:

```
'Datacenter: {{ item.0.name }}, Cluster: {{ item.1.name }}, Host: {{ item.2 }}'
```

But that does not work and I get the following error message instead:

```
Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ datacenters | subelements('clusters') | subelements('hosts') }}): the key hosts should point to a dictionary, got ...(the result of the first layer)
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49772057/11942268), which solves a similar problem, but relies on having distinct dict keys on all nesting levels, which I don't, because datacenters and clusters have the same `name` key.

So, how can I iterate over subelements of subelements in Ansible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit far-fetched but the following playbook will achieve your goal:

```yaml
 ---
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: false
 
   vars:
     datacenters:
     - name: Datacenter1
       clusters:
         - name: ClusterA
           hosts:
             - 192.168.0.1
             - 192.168.0.2
         - name: ClusterB
           hosts:
             - 192.168.1.1
             - 192.168.1.2
     - name: Datacenter2
       clusters:
         - name: ClusterC
           hosts:
             - 192.168.2.1
             - 192.168.2.2
 
     # Get the list of datacenters
     _dcs: "{{ datacenters | map(attribute='name') }}"
     # Get the corresponding list of clusters with subelements on hosts
     _clusters: "{{ datacenters | map(attribute='clusters') | map('subelements', 'hosts') }}"
     # Recreate a list with the sublisted hosts per clusters and create subelements on that final result
     _overall: "{{ dict(_dcs | zip(_clusters)) | dict2items(key_name='datacenter', value_name='clusters') | subelements('clusters') }}"
 
   tasks:
     - name: Loop on the result
       debug:
         msg:
           - "DC: {{ item.0.datacenter }}"
           - "Cluster: {{ item.1.0.name }}"
           - "Host: {{ item.1.1 }}"
       loop: "{{ _overall }}"
       loop_control:
         label: "{{ item.0.datacenter }} - {{ item.1.0.name }}"
```

This gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Loop on the result] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Datacenter1 - ClusterA) => {
    "msg": [
        "DC: Datacenter1",
        "Cluster: ClusterA",
        "Host: 192.168.0.1"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Datacenter1 - ClusterA) => {
    "msg": [
        "DC: Datacenter1",
        "Cluster: ClusterA",
        "Host: 192.168.0.2"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Datacenter1 - ClusterB) => {
    "msg": [
        "DC: Datacenter1",
        "Cluster: ClusterB",
        "Host: 192.168.1.1"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Datacenter1 - ClusterB) => {
    "msg": [
        "DC: Datacenter1",
        "Cluster: ClusterB",
        "Host: 192.168.1.2"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Datacenter2 - ClusterC) => {
    "msg": [
        "DC: Datacenter2",
        "Cluster: ClusterC",
        "Host: 192.168.2.1"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Datacenter2 - ClusterC) => {
    "msg": [
        "DC: Datacenter2",
        "Cluster: ClusterC",
        "Host: 192.168.2.2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```